# jQuery/CSS to create a Form for style choosing. That will change aspects of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

In class I am suppose to use the jQuery method of CSS to create a Form that allows the user to change aspects of the page.  I am struggling with the CSS part.  I created a function for the Form to Submit and also display the chosen results.  But cant figure out how to apply CSS to the form to change the page.  Any ideas or help would be great.  Thanks

```
  <form id="style-form">

<div>
 <label for="fontColor">Font Color</label>
 <select name="font-color" id="fontColor">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <label for="fontFamily">Font Family</label>
 <select name="font-family" id="fontFamily">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="times">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="monospace">Monospace</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <label for="fontSize">Font Size</label>
 <select name="font-size" id="fontSize">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</div>

</form>

<div id="results">
</div>

$(function() {
 $('#style-form').on('submit', function(evnt) {
  evnt.preventDefault();
 $('#results').html('');
   let elements = this.elements;
   let index = 0;
  while (elements.item(index) !== null) {
   let el = elements.item(index);
   el = $(el);
   let name = el.attr('name');
   let value = el.val();
   console.log(name + ': ' + value);
  $('#results').append('<p><strong>' + name + '</strong>: ' + 
   value + '</p>');
  index++;
  }
  });
  });
```

Comment: $('#results').css("background-color", "red"); will change the background color of the results box to red. The first parameter of the css() function is the css property. The second parameter is the desired value. You mentioned "jQuery method of CSS," which should indicate that there's a css() function in jQuery that you can search online.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to figure out or understand when the form is submitted the selected option can change the page.  Thast where I am having my problem.  So if someone was to select                      (FontColor:Blue),                                                                                   (Font Family: Arial),                                                                          (FontSize:16)                                                                                           Then hit submit. I want it to effect/change the styles of the page

Answer (score 0):

Change font-color to just color to change text color: 
`<select name="color" id="fontColor">`

You need font size units. Add a "px" to the font size:
`<option value="12px">12</option>`

Apply the css to a Dom element. You can use the body.
`$('body').css(name, value);`

This will answer your question. I replaced the `while` loop and the `i` counter to take advantage of jQuery's `each()` loop.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#style-form').on('submit', function(evnt) {
  evnt.preventDefault();
    $('#results').html('');
    $("#style-form option:selected").each(function(i){
      let $el = $(this);
      console.log($el.parent().attr('name') + " : " + $el.val());        
      $('#results').append('<p><strong>' + $el.parent().attr('name') + '</strong>: ' + 
      $el.val() + '</p>');  
      $('body').css($el.parent().attr('name'), $el.val());
    });
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="style-form">

<div>
 <label for="fontColor">Font Color</label>
 <select name="color" id="fontColor">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <label for="fontFamily">Font Family</label>
 <select name="font-family" id="fontFamily">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="times">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="monospace">Monospace</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <label for="fontSize">Font Size</label>
 <select name="font-size" id="fontSize">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="12px">12</option>
  <option value="14px">14</option>
  <option value="16px">16</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</div>

</form>
```

Font Family
 
  --Choose--
  Times New Roman
  Arial
  Monospace
 



 Font Size
 
  --Choose--
  12
  14
  16